# Paraphrasing the definition of a complete measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to paraphrase what it means for a measure to be complete, so that I can get a better grasp of the concept. Here are the relevant definitions from my textbook, *Real Analysis* by Folland:

> *If $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, a set $E \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(E) = 0$ is called a **null** set. A measure whose domain includes all subsets of null sets is called **complete.***

Then Folland gives the following theorem:

> **Thm 1.9.** *Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $\mathcal{N} := \{N \in \mathcal{M}: \mu(N) = 0\}$ and let  $$\overline{\mathcal{M}} := \{E \cup F: E \in \mathcal{M} \text{ and } F \subset N \text{ for some } N \in \mathcal{N} \}.$$
> $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and there is a unique extension $\overline{\mu}$ of $\mu$ to a complete measure on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$.*

> The measure $\overline{\mu}$ in Theorem 1.9 is called the **completion** of $\mu$, and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ is called the completion of $\mathcal{M}$ with respect to $\mu$.

I'm trying to write my own, equivalent, definitions of $\overline{\mu}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$. Here is my attempt:

**My definition.** Fix a nonempty set $X$, and then define
\begin{align*}
   S_X &:= \big\{\text{measure spaces } (X,\widehat{\mathcal{M}},\widehat{\mu}):  \widehat{\mu} \text{ is complete and extends } \mu   \big\}  \\[4pt]
     &\,= \big\{\text{measure spaces } (X,\widehat{\mathcal{M}},\widehat{\mu}):  \widehat{\mathcal{M}} \supset \mathcal{M} \cup \{\text{all subsets of } \widehat{\mu}\text{-null sets}  \} \text{ and }   \widehat{\mu}|_{\mathcal{M}} = \mu  \big\}.
\end{align*}

*Then there is a *unique* element $(X,\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{\mu})$ of $S_X$ such that $\overline{\mathcal{M}} \subset \widehat{\mathcal{M}}$ for every $(X,\widehat{\mathcal{M}},\widehat{\mu}) \in S_X$, and $\overline{\mu}$ is called the completion of $\mu$, and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ is called the completion of $\mathcal{M}$ with respect to $\mu$.*

Theorem 1.9 shows that Folland's definition of $\overline{\mu}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ implies my definition. Conversely, if $(X,\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{\mu})$ is defined according to Folland's definition, then clearly $(X,\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{\mu}) \in S_X$. Moreover, it's easy to verify that
\begin{align*}
     \overline{\mathcal{M}} = \sigma_X(\mathcal{M} \cup \{\text{all subsets of } \mu\text{-null sets}   \} ). 
\end{align*}

Also, for any measure $\widehat{\mu}$ extending $\mu$, it is clear that $ \{\text{subsets of } \widehat{\mu}\text{-null sets} \} \supset \{\text{subsets of } \mu\text{-null sets} \}$. Thus, for any $(X,\widehat{\mathcal{M}},\widehat{\mu}) \in S_X$ we have $\widehat{\mathcal{M}} \supset \mathcal{M} \cup \{\text{subsets of } \mu\text{-null sets} \}$, and hence $\overline{\mathcal{M}} \subset \widehat{\mathcal{M}}$, since $\sigma_X(\mathcal{M} \cup \{\text{subsets of } \mu\text{-null sets} \})$ is the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. So it seems that my definition implies Folland's definition, and hence they are equivalent.

In essence, what I'm trying to express in my definition is the following: $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{M}$ which admits a complete extension of $\mu$; said complete extension is unique, and is denoted by $\overline{\mu}$.

**My questions.**

1. Is this argument and definition correct? i.e. is my definition indeed equivalent to Folland's?
2. Is it possible for the set $S_X$ to contain more than one element? I've tried to come up with an example, but so far I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: @LukasHeger OP fixed the underlying space $X$, so it is not "the set of all measure spaces".

Comment: For (2), as a trivial example, any probability measure on any nontrivial $\sigma$-algebra on $S$ is an extension of the trivial probability measure on the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{S, \emptyset\}$, and many of them are likely to be complete.